# PHP/AJAX check if div is clicked and return data

Tags: php, ajax, html, menu, categories

How is possible to check if div is clicked and then return information?

```
function kat(){
echo "<div class='turinys'>";
$kategorijos = dbquery("SELECT * FROM kategorijos");
while($kat = dbarray($kategorijos)) {
    echo"<div class='kategorija'><a href='".BASEDIR."kategorija/".seoname($kat['kategorija'])."/".$kat['id']."' class='kat'>".trimlink($kat['kategorija'],44)."</a></div>";
}
echo "</div>";
}


echo "<div class='mygtukas-js' onclick='kat();'>";
echo "</div>";
```

But actually it's wrong because my mygtukas-js has a drop down menu.
I need to generate a code which let me to press a button and then menu would be generated. Maybe someone knows?

EDIT: This div `<div class='mygtukas-js'></div>` (**has to start and end before**) `<div class='turinys'>` STARTS.

Some fresh ideas? :?

EDIT2:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'>
</script>
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#mygtukas-js').click(function() {
                  $("#turinys").load('b.php');
                });
            });
        </script>
```

and b.php

```
<?php
$kategorijos = dbquery("SELECT * FROM kategorijos");
while($kat = dbarray($kategorijos)) {
    echo"<div class='kategorija'><a href='".BASEDIR."kategorija/".seoname($kat['kategorija'])."/".$kat['id']."' class='kat'>".trimlink($kat['kategorija'],44)."</a></div>";
}
?>
```

But no information generated :(

Comment: For starters you need an understanding of the difference between server-side and client-side script -- the "click" event happens on the client, but the PHP function is on the server.  You can't call server-side code directly from a client-side event without using AJAX or the equivalent.

Comment: I know. So therefore i need some examples of this issue.

Comment: Indeed, I have to use <div class='turinys'></div> necessarily After <div class='mygtukas-js'></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create your PHP file which I guess would also include HTML.
2. Create a "click" JQuery function and make sure to send the POST to the specific PHP file / Controller which should handle the request. In case you want to just get the above file directly then point to it.

It should be like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#send').click(function() {

     $("#menu").load('URL_TO_YOUR_PHP');

    });

});
```

Thanks to AJAX the "#menu" should be displayed and will contain whatever the PHP file sends back.

HTH.

Comment: Glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 0):

U can use jQuery to check if a div is clicked. Like this:

```
$('.turinys').click(function(e) {
  $(this).html("Add any html to the div");
});
```

Comment: Yes i know. But i need generate information with PHP to and insert it in remote/custom location.

Answer (score 0):

Use to different php file. Lets call A.php and B.php. A.php contain the menu code.

### A.php

```
<?php
echo "<div class='turinys'>";
$kategorijos = dbquery("SELECT * FROM kategorijos");
while($kat = dbarray($kategorijos)) {
    echo"<div class='kategorija'>
    <a href='".BASEDIR."kategorija/".seoname($kat['kategorija'])."/".$kat['id']."' class='kat'>".trimlink($kat['kategorija'],44)."</a>
    </div>";
}
echo "</div>";

?>
```

### B.php

```
 <script>
  function kat(){
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open("GET", "A.php", false);
     xhr.send(null);
     // You can also check response status if you need.
     var serverResponse = xhr.responseText;
     document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = serverResponse;
  }
 </script>
 <?php
    echo "<div class='mygtukas-js' onclick='kat();' id='menu'>";
    echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: Actually, I have to use <div class='turinys'>function to kat();</div>
After echo "<div class='mygtukas-js' onclick='kat();' id='menu'>";
    echo "</div>"; :(

Comment: Hmm.. I have to insert dynamic menu After end of the button. In other words, I have to add menu into custom location. Or for example i have to complete (</div>) and then create div with class turinys, but check if div was clicked only.